# Fetch and execute url from mysql db using php

Tags: php, mysql

I can't find a solution. All I want to do is fetch and execute a url/link stored as a record in my db. I dont want it returned as a link but a page loaded from this url/link php.

Comment: Show the code you have tried so far.

Comment: can somebody translate this to plain english :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [**file_get_contents**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)...

You need to fetch the link from database and then get the content using this function.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
        $con = mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');
        mysql_select_db('database_name');


        $sql  = "***`<select query here>`***";
        $res = mysql_query($sql);

        $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);

        $url = echo $row['url'];

        $contents = file_get_contents($url);
  ?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "execute a url". If you want to get the data at a URL, you can use `file_get_contents`, like this:

```
$url_content = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/page.html');
```

If you want to send the user to that url, you can use the `header` command with a `Location` header to send the browser to that address, ie.

```
header('Location: http://www.google.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose that the fetched variable is `$fetch`. In that case use:

```
header("location:$fetch");
```